# Integer value doesn't change after assignment in function

Tags: java

I just got simple problem, but it seems that I cant find a solution for it. Well the following code is part of open-source project, but this part is written by me from scratch.

Well, everything inside this "script" works well without problems except of one thing,
the `int` variable `CB_State` doesn't change after calling `StartParticipation()` method:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.Announcements;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.ThreadPoolManager;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.model.actor.instance.L2PcInstance;
import com.l2jserver.gameserver.network.serverpackets.NpcHtmlMessage;

public final class CastleBattle
{
    private static Logger _log = Logger.getLogger("CastleBattle");

    private static String htm_path = "data/scripts/l2dc/CastleBattle/";
    public static int CB_State = 1; // 0 - Disabled, 1 - Not running, 2 - Participation start, 3 - Participation end, 4 - Running, 5 - Event ended

    public CastleBattle()
    {
        CB_Init();
    }

    // Initialize Engine
    private static void CB_Init()
    {
        if (CB_State == 1)
        {
            SetStartTime();
        }
    }

    // Event Loop
    public static void SetStartTime()
    {
        Calendar _nextTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int _m = _nextTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int x = 1;
        while (_m > 5)
        {
            _m -= 5;
            x++;
        }
        _nextTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, x * 5);
        ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleGeneral(new CastleBattleLoop(), _nextTime.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    // Allow players to participate in the event
    public static void StartParticipation()
    {
        CB_State = 2;
        Announcements.getInstance().announceToAll("Castle Battle participation has started.");
        _log.info("Castle Battle participation has started.");
    }

    // Player requests to join event via NPC
    public static void CB_bypass(String _cmd, L2PcInstance _player)
    {
        if (_cmd.startsWith("InitHtmlRequest"))
        {
            if (CB_State == 0)
            {
                NpcHtmlMessage _html = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                _html.setFile("", htm_path + "CB_Disabled.htm");
                _player.sendPacket(_html);
            }
            if (CB_State == 1)
            {
                NpcHtmlMessage _html = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                _html.setFile("", htm_path + "CB_NotRunning.htm");
                _player.sendPacket(_html);
            }
            if (CB_State == 2)
            {
                NpcHtmlMessage _html = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                _html.setFile("", htm_path + "CB_Participate.htm");
                _player.sendPacket(_html);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        _log.info("# Castle Battle Engine #");
        _log.info("Author : HyperByter");
        _log.info("Version : Beta");
        _log.info("Version : 3.7.2013");
        new CastleBattle();
    }
}

class CastleBattleLoop implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (CastleBattle.CB_State == 1)
        {
            CastleBattle.StartParticipation();
        }
    }
}
```

So any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: It should, how and where do you determine that is doesn´t change? Does the function StartParticipation even get called?

Comment: Or perhaps another method call changes its value again. It's `public static`.

Comment: If the answers do not work, try `public static volatile int CB_State = 1;`

Comment: Argh, i hate it if users ask questions and don´t react if the nice answering people have a question of their own -.-

Comment: StartParticipation function is called from Run method at CastleBattleLoop ( this run function calls itself when timer at SetStartTime expires ) I got it confirmed because message "Castle Battle participation has started." appears in game, aswell in console, but CB_State in remains unchanged so its still "1"

Comment: When is it still 1? Directly after the line `CB_State = 2;`? I doubt that, so it happens somewhere else, somewhere we don´t have code about, improve your question, there is a reason you have 3 down-votes.

Comment: CB_State value within the StartParticipation changes to 2when i add following line for testing :
_log.info("" + CB_State);

but if i add same line to any other function, it says that CB_State is 1..

Answer (score 3):

The method `StartParticipation()` is probably never called:

- `main()` calls the constructor of `CastleBattle`
- The `CastleBattle` constructor calls `CB_Init()`
- `CB_Init()` calls `SetStartTime()`

`SetStartTime()` invokes this line:

```
ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleGeneral(new CastleBattleLoop(), _nextTime.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

after some whacky and indecipherable arithmetic on `_nextTime`, it's likely that the schedule interval is either very large, or perhaps negative, either of which may cause the Runnable CastleBattleLoop to never be started, in which case StartParticipation() would never be called.

I don't know what ThreadPoolManager does with strange input, but I would start by debugging what value is being passed into the scheduleGeneral() method and read the javadoc to see what effect such a value would have.

Comment: `ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleGeneral(new CastleBattleLoop(), _nextTime.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());` I don´t know exactly, what this code is doing but my guess would be that it creates a new thread which then calls `StartParticipation()`

Comment: I agree, can´t figure out how _nextTime is calculated or what it should even represent / do neither. thus +1.

Comment: StartParticipation function is called from Run method at CastleBattleLoop ( this run function calls itself when timer at SetStartTime expires )
I got it confirmed because message "Castle Battle participation has started." appears in game, aswell in console, but CB_State in remains unchanged so its still "1"

Answer (score 0):

The class at the bottom is called `CastleBattleLoop` , but it does not contain anything loopy, so `StartParticipation()` gets called only once (if `CB_State` is 1 at that moment).

You should add something like

```
while(running){
    if (CastleBattle.CB_State == 1)
    {
        CastleBattle.StartParticipation();
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StartParticipation() is being called inside a thread.
Check if you are trying to figure out its value even before actual change occurs.

[Not sure how are you figuring out the value of "CastleBattle.CB_State" in later part of the code]